# Display alert popup has white font color for options

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I have problem with Display alert function. Option text is not visible. I can click on it but text is not visible as show in picture

[image]

Code behind it is :

```
public async void AlertChange()
    {
        bool answer;

        answer = await DisplayAlert("test?", "Test question", "Yes", "No");

        if(answer)
        {
           .
           .
           . 
           .
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by changing colorAccent in styles.xml