# How to change button colors on .Net Maui DisplayAlert popup?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net Maui 7 app.

I'm showing a DisplayAlert as follows :

```
bool Answer = await DisplayAlert("Sure ?", "Are you sure ?", "Yes", "No");
```

The popup shows properly but the text of the buttons is white.

How can I change this color?

I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078451/display-alert-popup-has-white-font-color-for-options) but this does not seem to work for .Net Maui.

Comment: There have been discussion and proposal on how to change the button color of DisplayAlert in MAUI, you can refer to [Changing the DisplayAlert button color #6579](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/6579) and [Give developers more (full) control over control colors #7542](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7542).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1047020/change-the-button-color-in-alert-action-sheet-in-i

This worked for me
Basically go to "Platforms/Android/Resources/values/Colors.xml. " and change the primary color